# Database index on a column with duplicate values

Tags: mysql, sql, database, indexing, sybase

If there is a table containing details of employees including a column Gender whose value can be either M/F. Now would it make sense to create an index on this column, would it make the search faster? Logically if we fire a select statement with where clause containing Gender as the column, it should cut down the search time by half. But I have heard that this kind of index will not help and would be actually ignored by the Database Optimizer while executing the query. But I am not getting why? Can somebody please explain?

Comment: actually this question is in general, but yes Sybase in particular

Comment: I searched on internet but could not get clear answer, can the person giving me down vote please explain, why you are giving me down-vote. May be if its so simple for you, can you please put the answer as well

Comment: An index is just a phone book,if the names are varied its useful in cutting down the time to find somebodys number,if half the names in there are John then you need to search half the houses.I didnt downvote you.https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/402037ae-c9c0-4bbd-a7af-5862fd7ebf18/the-phone-book-analogy-for-an-index

Comment: So are you sure that if I create the index, it would cut down the search by half? Actually its not that simple, because it depends upon how database stores the indexes and how query optimizers work, and I heard that it may not be helpful, that's why i wanted in-depth clarity

Comment: It depends on many things:the number of rows,memory on your comp,cardinality,type of index,the columns used in WHERE and so on.For a single column in WHERE which will return half the values I doubt an index will be used.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the last part "For a single column in WHERE which will return half the values I doubt an index will be used.", because that's what I am not able to get clearly, why will it not be used if it can cut down the search by half ...

Comment: Its becasue of how an index works,like the branches of a tree so if you need a certain value or a small range the search is fast because the optimizer "walks" the tree from the trunk to the leaf which is fast,but if you are searching for many leaves its sometimes faster to scan the table then to use the index. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Indexing/68439/

Comment: Its bit of an art more than a science why dont you try it and see for yourself.

Comment: I agree, I will try this by creating a sample table... actually due to technical difficulties, I can't try it on the actual data. And I was trying to understand the underlying theoritical concepts behind it

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In most cases, only one index can be used to optimize a database query. If a query needs to match several indexed columns, the query planner will have to decide which of these indexes to use. Each index has a *cardinality*, which is roughly the number of different values across the table. An index with higher cardinality will be more effective, because selecting rows that match the index will result in very few rows to scan to match the other conditions.

An index on a `gender` column will only cut the table in half. Any other index will be more effective.

As an analogy, think of phone books. If you had a single phone book for an entire country, it would be huge and hard to search for the specific person you want. So phone books are usually made for just a city, or a few cities in an area, to make them reasonable sizes. But if you instead had a "Male phone book" instead of regional phone books, it would be nearly as unusable as a phone book for the entire country. The criteria for creating new phone books is that they should be much smaller than a book for the entire country. A factor of 2 reduction isn't very useful when you're starting with an enormous size.

Comment: Well, suppose my query is taking 1 hour to execute, and if I can get it executed in half an hour, its still a big saving for me ...

Comment: How often do you do that query? Remember, there's memory and time overhead for maintaining the index. So lots of other operations will be slowed down, and that may add up to more than the half hour you save on those occasional queries that only need the gender index.

Comment: its not a frequent query, it may be only a few times in a day

Comment: That's my point. Is it worth all the overhead of updating the index if it's rarely used?

Comment: From business standpoint, we need to finish the query fast due to certain SLA related reasons, the other operations as you rightly pointed out like inserts and updates may be delayed somewhat, but that's is acceptable if the impact is reasonable ...

Comment: Why don't you post the query and estimated rows for each of the tables.

Answer (score 8):

Presumably, gender take on two values.  In general, an index on `gender` would not be helpful.  In fact, it might be hurtful.

If you are selecting on gender, without an index, the query optimizer does a full table scan of the database pages to satisfy the query.  On a typical page, half the entries would match the query, so you would start getting results on the first hit.

In this phase of query execution, an index is typically used to reduce the number of pages being read.  However, if every page has a record with "M" and "F", then every page still has to be read.  To make matters worse, using an index means that you read from one random page, and then another, and another, instead of just reading the values sequentially.  Jumping around pages takes a bit extra time.  If the pages do not all fit in memory, you have a situation called thrashing, and it could take a really, really long time.

The one exception to this is a clustered index, where the values on the pages are actually sorted by the values.  In that case, a query using the index would be about 50% faster, because only have the pages need to be read.  This can be particularly effective in an "archive" table, where you have active records that are frequently searched.  This flag might occur on 10%, 1%, or 0.1% of the records, and the clustered index can be a significant speed improvement.

It would be rare on a large table to run a query that returns half the records.  Quite possibly, gender in combination with other columns would be a good candidate for inclusion in an index.